# OpenCV, how do I quantify a pixel changeing color throughout frames

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm trying to write this little piece of code with openCV that'll tell me how much an image changes color and based on that and a treshold it becomes part of one group or another.
What I have is a list of same images with slightly different colors.

Now these are the testimages and based on them I should somehow quantify the change in color and based on that let some other pictures through or not.

I thought about getting the average, but that's just a brownish yellow which is not a good measure.
I thought about dominant color, but as the picture changes color throughout...
But I have no idea what else I can try.
Is there a way to set up a colorrange to which a series of pictures must adhere to validate?

If someone can help me in a direction that would be awesome!

As requested a sample 1st picture:
[image]

2nd picture: [image]
3rd picture: [image]

The list of pictures is a list of this picture but slightly darker or lighter tones, slightly more or less reflective.
All the code I wrote up to now is just to get a list of ROI's which I can analyse.

EDIT:
The shape is always the same shape, the background is too. Only the color seems to change as well as the brightness.
I have now plotted RG&B values in a time series. Which does not say a lot.
I am now trying to divide brightness out of the equation by evaluating the difference of color in the background (as it shouldn't change every difference should be due to brightness) and use that coefficient to weight the R, G & B channels with.
I'll keep you guys updated. [image: RG&B plotted throughout +/- 60 frames]

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the images.

Comment: please include your code we are not mind readers

Comment: Is it always on that same background? Does the red object change position/shape/size  between frames?

Comment: Perhaps histogram matching. See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/. Or threshold and do shape matching. See https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for the tips, I'm reading through your information right now. Sadly only shape-matching is not enough. 
It should match shape, location, and specific change in color.

Comment: If there is no rotation or scale changes, use template matching.

Comment: @fmw42 today I will be trying out histogram matching and template matching, thanks for the tips !!

Answer (score 2):

I think a slightly different approach might be better:

- rather than normalising away the background brightness variations, I thought of removing the background altogether by flood filling starting in the top-left corner
- rather than look at the RGB values, convert to [HSV colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and look at the image there.

So, I renamed your 3 frames as `f-1.png`, `f-2.png` and `f-3.png` and ran this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pathlib

def ProcessOne(filename):
   """Process a single image for the Hue, Saturation and Value of the foreground pixels"""
   # Load image
   im = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

   # Segment to get interesting area
   grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   _, th = cv2.threshold(grey,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
   ff = th.copy()
   h, w = th.shape[:2]
   mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
   # Floodfill from (0, 0)
   cv2.floodFill(ff, mask, (0,0), 255);
   res = ~(th | ~ff)

   # This is all debug and can be removed
   cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-grey.png',grey)
   cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-th.png',th)
   cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-mask.png',mask)
   cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-ff.png',ff)
   cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-res.png',res)

   # Convert original image to HSV and split channels
   HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
   H, S, V = cv2.split(HSV)
   maskedHue = np.ma.masked_where(res,H)
   meanHue   = maskedHue.mean()
   maskedSat = np.ma.masked_where(res,S)
   meanSat   = maskedSat.mean()
   maskedVal = np.ma.masked_where(res,V)
   meanVal   = maskedVal.mean()
   print(f'Filename: {filename}, Hue: {meanHue}, Sat: {meanSat}, Val: {meanVal}')

# Process all frames f-XXX.png
for filename in pathlib.Path.cwd().glob('f-*.png'):
   ProcessOne(filename.name)
```

---

[image] [image] [image]

I got these results:

```
Filename: f-1.png, Hue: 166.95651173492868, Sat: 125.59134836631385, Val: 116.88587206626784
Filename: f-2.png, Hue: 141.85912185959145, Sat: 62.537684902559285, Val: 64.28621742193003
Filename: f-3.png, Hue: 163.32165750915752, Sat: 110.39972527472527, Val: 90.87522893772893
```

Hopefully you can see:

- the first image is saturated (Hue=125) and bright valued (Val=116)
- the second image is greyer, or less saturated (Sat=62), and darker (Val=64)
- the third image is nearly as saturated and nearly as bright as the first

---

Note that you can do something very similar just in the Terminal with **ImageMagick**. Here I crop out a 30x30 pixel square (marked in cyan) starting at offset (40,40) from the top-left corner.

[image]

Then I average the pixels by resizing it to 1x1 and convert to HSV colourspace and print the results as text:

```
magick f-1.png -crop 30x30+40+40 -resize 1x1\! -colorspace HSV txt:

0,0: (343.898,50.9512%,45.2334%)  #F48273  hsv(343.898,50.9512%,45.2334%)
```

and

```
magick f-2.png -crop 30x30+40+40 -resize 1x1\! -colorspace HSV txt:

0,0: (353.646,26.5537%,24.0175%)  #FA443D  hsv(353.646,26.5537%,24.0175%)
```

and

```
magick f-3.png -crop 30x30+40+40 -resize 1x1\! -colorspace HSV txt:

0,0: (346.963,45.7643%,35.3905%)  #F6755A  hsv(346.963,45.7643%,35.3905%)
```

It obviously uses a slightly different area of the image and a different range of values, but if you look at the last field, namely `hsv(...)`, you can see it follows the same pattern as the Python.

Comment: Thank you very much! That really is a whole other approach! I will try that out, plot out all the differences and see if I can come up with some kind of trend. 
If I do I'll post an update. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I tested this, I additionally divided by the background value, to divide out any brightness factor. I did this for RGB and for HSV, I then normalised the outcome, based on green and sorted all the results. 
Now I do find rather steady result going up for red, blue seems to be all over the place. Same for H, rather steady, the rest all over the place. 
Nonetheless, your help was greatly appreciated and solid. Thanks a lot for that!